# Primefaces: global message not showing in dialog on first access

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

i am trying to show a globalMessage in the main form as well as within a dialog. The message within the dialog only shows when the dialog is opened a second time.

I can't get it to work. Can anyone solve this problem? I'd really appreciate it!

I am using JSF Mojarra 2.2.1, Primefaces 4.0 and Apache Tomcat 7.0.

Here is my view (testView.xhtml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" 
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" 
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head></h:head>

<h:body>
    <h:form id="testForm">
        <p:messages globalOnly="true" showDetail="true" closable="true" />
        <p:commandButton value="ClickMe" action="#{testBean.displayMessage()}" 
            update="testForm :testDialogForm" oncomplete="PF('testDialog').show()" />
    </h:form>

    <p:dialog id="testDialogId" widgetVar="testDialog" 
        dynamic="true" closable="true" closeOnEscape="true"
        header="Dialog with message">
        <h:form id="testDialogForm">
            <p:messages globalOnly="true" showDetail="true" closable="true" />
            <h:outputText value="This outputText should not be alone." />
        </h:form>
    </p:dialog>
</h:body>
```

Here is my bean (TestBean.java):

```
package de.simply.local.tbx.webbeans;

import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

@ManagedBean(name = "testBean")
@ViewScoped
public class TestBean {

    public void displayMessage() {

        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null,
                new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO,
                        "This is the summary.", "These are the details."));
    }

}
```

Comment: How is it if you put autoupdate on them?

Comment: the growl is better suited for your needs. Try turning off the `dynamic` on the dialog

Comment: @kolossus: thanks, i removed the dynamic attribute and it works now, thanks!